# Getting a 500 internal server error on rails app (heroku log posted)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

**Update**
I solved it. There were some issues with the if statements in the code

Everything works fine locally but I'm not sure why I'm getting errors

I have my rails app and I'm trying to access URL "/users/username" such as tbrown for example. Is it caused just by the undefined method "admin" or something else? Admin_user is already defined in my application_controller.rb and I have a admin_user.rb model. Post here are the heroku logs and the controller

heroku logs

```
2013-03-20T08:05:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/tbrown" for xx.xx.xx
.xx at 2013-03-20 08:05:55 +0000
2013-03-20T08:05:55+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <% end %></div>
2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined met
hod `admin?' for nil:NilClass):
2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <% if current_user.admin? %>
 2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <span class="content2"><%= com
ment.comment_content %></span>
2013-03-20T08:05:56+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <%= link_to "delete", pos
t, method: :delete,
```

application_controller

```
def admin_user?
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_url
      return false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `app/views/posts/_post.html.erb` view on line:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
```

This assumes that current_user is not nil (i.e. a user is logged in). You are already defensively coding around that problem in your controller `admin_user?` method. It might be better to implement a helper method along the same lines (but without the redirect) and call that from your view instead.

Comment: thanks, it was the problem with user being logged in vs logged out causing the error